# Filter a collection for everything except the values in an array (exclude the values in the array)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, lodash

Trying out the lodash _.filter to return an array of values that excludes the values in an array. Say I have a collection of objects:

```
let col = {
    data: {
        name: "data1",
        type: "neighbor"
   },
},
{
    data: {
        name: "data2",
        type: "subordinate"
    }
},
{
    data: {
        name: "data3",
        type: "affiliate"
    }
}

let values = ["neighbor", "affiliate"];
```

I know I can do something like:

```
const elementsToKeep = _.filter(col, (v) => _.includes(values, v.data("type")));
```

which would return "neighbor" and "affiliate" but I want to return "subordinate" instead.  I know this should be rather simple but I'm having a hard time figuring it out without writing more extensive logic.

Comment: `_.filter(col, (v) => !_.includes(values, v.data("type")))`

Comment: ^ Thinker is correct. Also your object is invalid. You have an array of objects, but do not include `[]`. Make sure to wrap the very first and very last brace in brackets.

Comment: @BeerusDev yes, you're correct I did forget the [] in my code sample.. it was just a unintended omission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the data is not structured properly as @BeerusDev mentioned, let me add the code as the answer and try to explain it.

```js
const col = [{
    data: {
      name: "data1",
      type: "neighbor"
    },

  },
  {
    data: {
      name: 'data2',
      type: 'subordinate'
    }
  },
  {
    data: {
      name: "data3",
      type: "affiliate"
    }
  }
];

let values = ["neighbor", "affiliate"];

const elementsToKeep = _.filter(col, (v) => !_.includes(values, v.data["type"]));

console.log(elementsToKeep)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Since the result of the `_.includes` is a boolean value, to get the data which is not inside the array that u have, we need to use `!_.includes(...)`

Comment: simple enough.  I had tried something similar and it was returning a boolean, but I see what my issue was now.  This did work.  Thanks!